# List Manager CSV Upload Import Field AutoMap settings not working

Tags: list-manager

In Sitecore 8.1 (and 8.2) List Manager, we want to customize the data that we upload through CSV into custom Contact facets.

[image: CSV Upload with Custom Fields]

> This question is not asking how to add facets, and assumes that I have already correctly added facets to my contact model.

In order to do so, we have to add a **`ImportModelField`** item under the `ImportModel` on the `ImportWizardDialog` box.

[image: ImportModelField]

***Question:*** I have not been able to figure out how/why the `AutoMap` or `AutoMapSource` check boxes exists. Does anyone know how to use this appropriately?

**Findings Thus Far:**

- When **`AutoMap`** is checked, the field is hidden from the Map modal above. However, the data stored in the facet (noted by **`DataField`**) ends up being an email address, no matter how I attempt to map it.
- When **`AutoMapSource`** is checked, it doesn't appear as though anything really *auto maps* since I have to map the field anyways through the Map dialog.
- When both are checked, I just get an email address where I would've expected data from the CSV.

> **ASSUMPTIONS**
>
> - I have validated that the CSV file uploads as expected into the associated facets when I manually map the File field to the Sitecore Field.
> - I assume and would expect that if my "FieldName" and CSV Header are identical, it should map. (It appears this is a false assumption)

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question about how to do this, but I have an option for an alternative tool (which may be useful if you only need to run this once): Data Exchange Framework.

The [developer documentation](http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v1.1/implementing-a-provider/index.html) describes how to create a provider that can read a CSV file. Then you can configure the CSV file as the source system and xDB as the target system.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Conn! Appreciate the feedback, I think that your response does add some value. At the same time, we are targeting a method so that client users can upload a CSV file in order to create a list, while at the same time, store information about the contact. This is being utilized most in Email Experience Manager (EXM) when creating recipient lists. During upload, we add meta data that is then tracked when emails are opened, clicked, etc.

Comment: Yes, in that case you do need to get the product working as it is supposed to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AutoMap` and `AutoMapSource` fields are used to configure *automatic mapping* of the contact identifiers:

[image]

When configured, one does not have to select a *File field* manually in a dropdown. The *auto-mapped* field is hidden on UI and the value for that field is taken from another field marked as `AutoMapSource`.

By default, 'Email address' is used as a source for the contact Identifier field.

Comment: Sergey is correct.  The AutoMap and AutoMapSource check boxes are ONLY for mapping the identifier and are only meant to be used for the identifier field. Thus answering the original question.  The functionality I was looking for, which was automapping the CSV fields to the Import Model Fields, does not exist. I have since customized Sitecore's ImportMapTo rendering to do just that. I will be blogging about it in the coming week.